# exexuting external native file for vmake

Tags: android, opencv

I imported one NDK,cmake project in a android studio. But while building it i am getting this error. I had never worked on NDK before. I am new in NDK

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> executing external native build for cmake C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ocvdoc\app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt